# IP to name (FQDN) in browser URL

Tags: dns, firewall, esxi

I have a small lab setup as follows.

- A Windows Server with DNS service (192.168.31.165/27)
- An OPNSense Firewall (192.168.31.131/27)
- An ESXi Server (192.168.31.197/27)

Both the Windows Server and ESXi host are in different subnets and connected to the Firewall.

If I do an nslookup from ESXi via SSH I get the DNS resolved results both ways as in Image 1.

But if I enter the IP address in the URL of the browser to access the ESXi Web GUI the IP address does not change to the name of the ESXi as in the DNS A Record (Image 2). How do I achieve having the browser change the IP to name when opening the ESXi.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nywka.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/macAk.png)

Comment: browsers do not change IPs to FQDNs, for this your website should do a redirect to the FQDN if it is accessed via IP. you can see a different behaviour if you ping www.google.com and use the result IP in the browser it will bring you to google, while the same action for www.microsoft.com will not.

Comment: *for this your website should do a redirect to the FQDN if it is accessed via IP* how (or where) can I do it from that's what I wanted to know. Whether it is through some firewall setting, DNS server setting ?!, thanks..

Comment: have you ever tried access the website by fully qualified domain? if that's the case, please refer to:https://superuser.com/questions/1361680/cant-access-website-by-ip-but-i-can-access-by-fully-qualified-domain

Comment: Appreciate that, I believe I'm getting the picture now, and yes I can access the site by its FQDN, appreciate the help guys, thanks a lot..